# python module called with cat and command line arguments parser

Tags: python, parsing, arguments, cat

```
cat hello.txt | python main.py foobar
```

what is the reason of using `cat` here?

I understand `foobar` is command line argument so I need to handle it with arguments parser. how to handle it if i do not specify parameter e.g. `--parameters` ?

what about `hello.txt` used after `cat`?

is it the name of the file that i am passing into `python main.py` call as other argument or am I dumping `python main.py` execution results into `hello.txt`? how and what exactly? am I catching what `python main.py` is printing with `cat` and writing it into `hello.txt`?

EDIT:

Am i capturing it correct?

```
import argparse
import sys


def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('a', nargs='*')

    args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
    return args

file_content = data = sys.stdin.read()
params = parse_arguments()

print(file_content)
print(params)
```

Comment: this is basic os shell. That says run "cat" which prints out the contents of "hello.txt" and then pipe that to the standard input of "python main.py ..." (same as if you just ran python, and then used the keyboard)

Comment: Hey, thank you for the comment. I understand the first part but I do not get how to catch the file or its content in within main.py.

Comment: What file? It's just the standard input. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454365/what-does-sys-stdin-read

Comment: hello.txt is a file with some content. when you call cat hello.txt then you print it to the screen. how to capture it in main.py?

Comment: No, it's not a file any more. It replaced sys.stdin (that happened in the operating system, before python started)

Comment: I have just updated my question. It is  a file all the time as it is created as hello.txt. I understand calling it with cat prints file content to stdin

Comment: Or just use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404068/how-to-read-keyboard-input

Comment: No mate, I do not want to use keyboard input. I am asking how to capture in main.py stdin print results of call cat on a file and you provide me sth else. I am asking for bike and you advice me to use a bus.

Comment: This is basic os shell. Look up piping to standard input. Your keyboard has been replaced with the contents of "hello.txt" (This is an operating system question, not a python question.)

Comment: Ok, I have solved the part with cat hello.txt but I am still unsure about foobar part

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html or just look at sys.argv I found those and several tutorials googling "python command line arguments"